# List view accessing a database not scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-sqlite

My android app's search activity uses a list view to display search results and each item of the list view is obtained from a SQLite database stored in the assets folder. The problem is that the list view scrolling is not smooth. Please help me.

My code:

DatabaseOpenHelper class:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String dbname="minip5.db";
    private static final int dbversion=1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context){
        super(context,dbname,null,dbversion);
    }
}
```

DatabaseAccess class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseAccess {
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    public Cursor c;
    //private constructor so that object creation from outside the class 
    is avoided
    private DatabaseAccess(Context context){
        this.openHelper=new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }
    //to return single instance of database
    public static DatabaseAccess  getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance==null)
            instance=new DatabaseAccess(context);
        return instance;
    }

    //to open database
    public void open(){
        this.db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void close(){
        if (db!=null)
        this.db.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<searchadapter> st(){
        ArrayList<searchadapter> sea=new ArrayList<>();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                searchadapter a=new searchadapter(c.getString(0));
                sea.add(a);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return sea;
    }
    public void run2(String name){
        c=db.rawQuery("select land.State, Avg_Land_Rate, 
        Annual_Avg_Temp_inC, No_of_Companies, annual_avg_rain_inCm, 
        No_of_Schools, No_of_Malls, No_of_Colleges, No_of_Pubs, 
        Literacy_rate_inPercent, Rank_in_Crime_Rate from land, company, 
        education, people, recreation, weather where 
        upper(land.state)='"+name+"' and land.State=company.State and " 
        +"land.State_code=education.State_code and 
        land.State_code=people.State_code 
        land.State_short_code=recreation.State_short_code "+"and 
        land.State_short_code=weather.State_short_code",new String[]{});
    }
```

searchadapter class:

```
public class searchadapter {
    private String st;
    public searchadapter(String st){
        this.st=st;
    }
    public String getSt(){
        return st;
    }
    public void setSt(String st){
        this.st=st;
    }
}
```

searchad class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class searchad extends ArrayAdapter<searchadapter> {
    private Context mcontext;
    private int mresource;
    private int lastpos=-1;

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView state;
    }

    public searchad(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<searchadapter> objects){
        super(context,resource,objects);
        mcontext=context;
        mresource=resource;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        String state=getItem(pos).getSt();
        searchadapter sa=new searchadapter(state);

        final View result;

        searchad.ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(mresource,parent,false);
            holder=new searchad.ViewHolder();
            holder.state=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtst);
            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder=(searchad.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

searchint class:(the search result activity class)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class searchint extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchint);
        search();
    }
    ListView listView;
    public void search(){
        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsearch);
        listView.setClickable(true);
        DatabaseAccess d=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        d.open();
        ArrayList<searchadapter> a=d.st();
        d.close();
        searchad adapter1=new searchad(searchint.this,R.layout.search,a);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
            position, long id) {
                TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtst);
                String st=tv.getText().toString();
                DatabaseAccess 
                d=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                d.open();
                d.run2(st.toUpperCase());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                searchres.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_searchint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
    tools:context=".searchint">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lsearch"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="587dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue may be due to the number of rows that may be extracted.

In short the number of rows extracted will be the progressive multiplication of the number of matching rows per table.

that is if the is state is x and there are :-

- 10 land rows with state x
- 4 company rows with state x
- 3 education rows with state x
- 3 people rows with state x
- 3 recreation rows with state x and
- 3 weather rows with state x

The result will be 3,240 rows from what would appear to be a relatively small amount of data.

Consider perhaps a more reasonable useful/usable amount of data such as :-

- 30 land rows with state x
- 20 company rows with state x
- 10 education rows with state x
- 10 people rows with state x
- 10 recreation rows with state x and
- 10 weather rows with state x

Then 6,000,000 rows would be generated, even though really the useful data could be represented as 90 rows

### Testing Example

Consider the following that was used to mimic your query :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weather;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recreation;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS education;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS land;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS state;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS land (landid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_reference INTEGER,  state TEXT, state_code TEXT, state_short_code TEXT, land_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company (companyid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_reference INTEGER, state TEXT, company_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS education (educationid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_reference INTEGER, state_code TEXT, education_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (peopleid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_reference INTEGER, state_code TEXT, people_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recreation (recreationid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_reference INTEGER, state_short_code TEXT, recreation_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather (weatherid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_reference INTEGER, state_short_code TEXT, weather_name TEXT);

-- State Table added to save typing NOTE state_reference was included in all tables to allow state, state_code and state_short_code to be applied automatically (see updates) 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS state (stateid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_name TEXT UNIQUE, state_code TEXT UNIQUE, state_short_code TEXT UNIQUE );

-- Build the states (20 should be plenty for testing)
INSERT INTO state (state_name, state_code, state_short_code) VALUES
    ('Alabama','alab','AL'),
  ('Alaska','alas','AK'),
    ('Arizona','ariz','AZ'),
    ('Arkansas','arka','AR'),
    ('California','cali','CA'),
    ('Colorado','colo','CO'),
    ('Connecticut','conn','CT'),
    ('Delaware','dela','DE'),
    ('Florida','flor','FL'),
    ('Georgia','geor','GA'),
    ('Hawaii','hawa','HI'),
    ('Idaho','idah','ID'),
    ('Illinois','illi','IL'),
    ('Indiana','indi','IN'),
  ('Iowa','iowa','IA'),
  ('Kansas','kans','KS'),
    ('Kentucky','kent','KY'),
    ('Louisiana','loui','LA'),
    ('Maine','main','ME'),
    ('Maryland','mary','MD')
;

-- Insert into the 6 tables randomly generating a state reference
INSERT INTO land (land_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('LandA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('LandZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Land0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;

INSERT INTO company (company_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('CompA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('CompZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Comp0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;

INSERT INTO education (education_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('EducA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;

INSERT INTO education (education_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('EducA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('EducZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Educ0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;

INSERT INTO people (people_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('ppplA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('ppplZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('pppl0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;

INSERT INTO recreation (recreation_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('recrA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recrZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('recr0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;

INSERT INTO weather (weather_name,state_reference) VALUES 
    ('WthrA', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrB', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrC', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrD', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrE', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrF', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrG', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrH', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrI', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrJ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrK', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrL', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrM', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrN', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrO', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrP', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrQ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrR', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrS', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrT', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrU', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrV', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrW', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrX', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrY', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('WthrZ', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr1', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr2', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr3', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr4', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr5', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr6', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr7', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr8', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr9', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
    ,('Wthr0', (SELECT abs(random() % 20) + 1))
;


-- Update the tables to apply the text for the state, state_code and state_short_code 
UPDATE land SET 
    state = (SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference), 
    state_code = (SELECT state_code FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference),
    state_short_code = (SELECT state_short_code FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference)
;

UPDATE company SET
    state = (SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference)
;

UPDATE education SET
    state_code = (SELECT state_code FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference)
;

UPDATE people SET
    state_code = (SELECT state_code FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference)
;

UPDATE recreation SET
    state_short_code = (SELECT state_short_code FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference)
;

UPDATE weather SET
    state_short_code = (SELECT state_short_code FROM state WHERE stateid = state_reference)
;

-- Just in case the tables need to be checked
SELECT * FROM land ;
SELECT * FROM company;
SELECT * FROM education;
SELECT * FROM people;
SELECT * FROM recreation;
SELECT * FROM weather;


-- Now try the query as per the question (well close to it)
-- EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
SELECT *
FROM 
    land,company, education, people, recreation, weather 
WHERE upper(land.state)= upper('Maine') 
    AND land.State=company.State 
    AND land.State_code=education.State_code 
    AND land.State_code=people.State_code 
  AND land.State_short_code=recreation.State_short_code 
    AND land.State_short_code=weather.State_short_code
;

-- Calculate the permutations
WITH counts AS ( SELECT 
        (SELECT count() FROM land WHERE upper(state) = upper('Maine')) AS landcount ,
        (SELECT count() FROM company WHERE upper(state) = upper('Maine')) AS companycount,
        (SELECT count() FROM education WHERE upper(state_code) = upper('main')) AS educationcount,
        (SELECT count() FROM people WHERE upper(state_code) = upper('main')) AS peoplecount,
        (SELECT count() FROM recreation WHERE upper(state_short_code) = upper('ME')) AS recreationcount,
        (SELECT count() FROM weather WHERE upper(state_short_code) = upper('ME')) AS weathercount
    )
SELECT *, (landcount * companycount * educationcount * peoplecount * recreationcount * weathercount) AS permutations FROM counts;
```

### Results

Running the above has produced from 0 to over 1000 rows (relatively low risk of rows being created for Maine (PS DO NOT remove the WHERE clause an attempt will be made to generate 2,176,782,336 rows (tried this it crashed after around 10 minutes and I had to restart PC))).

More often than not there will be 0 rows that match all the criteria. However here's the results from a run that produced 90 rows :-

First the permutations (the last query) :-

[image]

Some of the resultant data, which as you can see will likely be annoying once get any reasonable amount of data :-

[image]

Comment: I have exactly 36 rows in each table right now and the database is to be used only for reading purposes. So the max no. of rows that will be extracted in each list view is 36. Also the rows are extracted by using data from max 2 tables. What about this scenario?

Comment: @varunj6v1k9 Using two tables the maximum possible (without a where clause as such) would be 36 * 36 = 1296 rows. Perhaps try that and see how the list view reacts.

Comment: that is exactly how I'm using the database and the list view is laggy. Maybe something in the code???